# Prisma: Insert foreign key referencing non existing Record

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to model a m:n relation which references entries which might not exist yet on one side.

I tried with the following schema (doesn't work):

```
model Foo {
  id Int @id
}

model Bar {
  id Int @id
}

model FooBar {
  fooId Int
  barId Int

  foo Foo  @relation(fields: [fooId], references: [id])
  bar Bar? @relation(fields: [barId], references: [id])

  @@id([fooId, barId])
}
```

When trying to add a relation between `fooId: 1` (existing) and `barId: 1` (not existing (yet?)), I get the following error:

> Type: undefined
> Message:
> Invalid `prisma.fooBar.create()` invocation:
>
> An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. No 'Bar' record(s) (needed to inline the relation on 'fooBar' record(s)) was found for a nested connect on one-to-many relation 'fooBarToBar'.
>
> Code: P2025

Is there a way to insert the relation anyway, and when querying `Foo` with `{ include: { fooBar: { include: { bar: true }}}}` to receive an object like this when Bar doesn't exist:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  fooBar: {
    fooId: 1,
    barId: 1,
    bar: null
  }
}
```

I tried with the above schema, but it doesn't work. I guess changing the relation to this would work:

```
model FooBar {
  fooId Int
  barId Int

  barIdExisting Int?

  foo Foo  @relation(fields: [fooId], references: [id])
  bar Bar? @relation(fields: [barIdExisting], references: [id])
}
```

And then only set `barIdExisting` to `barId` if `bar` exists, but this would mean to have redundant data.

Comment: I have found https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7351, which suggests that this is not possible yet. But maybe someone still has a suggestion for a workaround.